# How to get window.close(); to work correctly in firefox and opera?

Tags: javascript

I am searching for window.close(); functionality, ideally it should work in firefox and opera so normal user can close the current window on button click.

For example, I know that if I change the configuration setting of Firefox using `about:config` and to set `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` to true, `window.close()` will work, but normal users don't know about setting. Is there any way I can enable this setting programatically?

code I am trying to test:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="close_win()">close</button>
<script>
  function closewin(){
    window.open('', '_self');
    window.close();
    return false;
  }
</script/>
```

Comment: Browsers already come with a 'close window' button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code. Its an alternate code for closing window

```
function clsWindow() {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    window.open('','_self');
    window.close();
}
clsWindow();
```

Now this might not work in the new versions of firefox if they have patched it. But Mozilla Firefox doesn't support any scripts to close the current tab/window. This is a workaround that did the trick for me.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried this before and it's showing this error: TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined )  trying on console

Comment: I have also read this forum when i was searching for this and as i wrote above that i wanted a solution for normal users so they don't get problem like this. well thanks for your time to took for this.

Comment: This is the closest that i could find and know. Ok but if thats the case then i have to say that AFAIK FireFox does not support scripts to close windows, for security reasons. Anyways Let me know if you get what you are looking for.